# ParseQuery - and between two columns

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am using Parse for my application.
I have class(Messages) with columns 'fromId','toId' etc..
I am looking for the best way to make query that give me the rows that contains id1 or id2 from column 'fromId' **AND** id1 or id2 from 'toId', that's mean that i'm looking for the messages that id1 send to id2 or the messages that id2 send to id1. 
Example code:

```
    ParseQuery<Message> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Message.class);

    query.orderByAscending("createdAt");
    query.whereContainedIn("FromId",fromIds/*list of id1,id2*/);
    query.whereContainedIn("toId",fromIds/*list of id1,id2*/);
    .....
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood you are looking for an `OR`-like query, not an `AND`. For that, [here is the official reference](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#queries-compound-queries).

In short you should create two different queries and merge them together with `ParseQuery.or()`:

```
ParseQuery<Message> from = ParseQuery.getQuery("Message");
from.whereContainedIn("fromId",list);

ParseQuery<Message> to = ParseQuery.getQuery("Message");
to.whereContainedIn("toId",list);

List<ParseQuery<Message>> queries = new ArrayList<ParseQuery<ParseObject>>();
queries.add(from);
queries.add(to);

ParseQuery<Message> mainQuery = ParseQuery.or(queries);
mainQuery.findInBackground(...);
```